# Lookup or If Condition Formula in MS Excel

Tags: excel

I need some help for a lookup formula in excel sheet. I am basically trying to find out a corresponding value of for a row, where two conditions in the same row meet. Let me illustrate it his way. If within the range of column A a certain value is found and in the same row but in Column C other certain value is equal then return the value in Column B for the same row.

The table is as follows:

```
Column A      Column B                        Column C 
---------------------------------------------------------
Ahmadaba      Irrigation                      550,041 
Ahmadaba      Livelihood                      18,890 
Ahmadaba      Power                           233,694 
Ahmadaba      Public Building                 64,707 
Ahmadaba      Rural Development               104,381 
Ahmadaba      Transport                       1,044,644 
Ahmadaba      Water Supply & Sanitation       1,156,322
```

To elaborate; in reference to above table if Column A is equal to Ahmadaba and Column C is equal to 18,890 then I should get the value Livelihood from column B.

Answer (score 1):

By far the least resource-heavy (and therefore most efficient) set-up would be to use one additional column within your table in which to generate a series of unique identifiers based on the entries in columns A and C.

So if your table is currently in, for example, `A1:C8` (with headers in row 1), then you could use column D to this end, entering this formula in `D2`:

`=A2&"|"&C2`

(The separator is probably not strictly necessary in your case, though in general it is good practice.)

and copied down to `D8`.

After which, and assuming your chosen search values, e.g. "Ahmadaba" and "18,890" are in `E1` and `F1` respectively, the required formula is:

`=INDEX(B2:B8,MATCH(E1&"|"&F1,D2:D8,0))`

Note that one of the advantages of this set-up is that you can also employ a more flexible variation of the above which references not just 8 rows but an entire column's worth, viz:

`=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E1&"|"&F1,D:D,0))`

with virtually no detriment to calculation performance.

If, for whatever reason, you cannot use an additional column within your table to  perform these concatenations, then an alternative solution would be:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/((A2:A8=E1)*(C2:C8=F1)),B2:B8)`

However, it should be pointed out that, with this set-up, the amount of calculation Excel has to perform is directly proportional to the size of the range being referenced. As such, unlike with the `INDEX`/`MATCH` construction, it would be a **disastrous** idea here to use:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/((A:A=E1)*(C:C=F1)),B:B)`

which is forcing Excel to calculate more than 2 million cells.

Regards